# Lista randômica em Query Linq to Entity C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Gostaria de pegar uma lista de 3 objetos dentro de uma query Link.

```
var listaPessoas = from i in this.Context.CreateObjectSet<listaPessoas>()
        select i;
...
listaPessoas  = listaPessoas .Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(filtro.Nome);
...
return listaPessoas;
```

Porém, neste retorno eu gostaria de pegar apenas 3 objetos (sempre aleatórios) dentro dos elementos em `listaPessoas`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use um objeto `Random` para ordenar a lista e o método `Take` para limitar a quantidade de itens retornados.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
listaPessoas = listaPessoas.OrderBy(p => rnd.Next()).Take(3).ToList();
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xsv0Ld)

Como você quer fazer isso no banco, vai precisar de algo diferente. Uma forma de fazer, é ordenar por um `Guid`, como não é possível saber o que vai ser gerado, a ordenação será randômica.

```
listaPessoas.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3).ToList();
```

Essa opção é ótima porque não aumenta significativamente o tamanho da *query* e nem a complexidade dela.

Comment: em meu projeto recebo este erro. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Next()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @BrunoHeringer Você deveria ter dito que está usando Entity Framework. Você quer fazer essa randomização no banco ou em memória?

Comment: Pode ser no banco mesmo.

Comment: @BrunoHeringer Dei uma opção

Comment: Mandou bem @Link. Top. Vlw

Answer (score 3):

Melhor maneira de usar é com [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (algoritmo para gerar uma permutação aleatória de uma sequência finita)

Crie uma extensão:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Shuffle(new Random());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (rng == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rng");

        return source.ShuffleIterator(rng);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> ShuffleIterator<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        List<T> buffer = source.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Count; i++)
        {
            int j = rng.Next(i, buffer.Count);
            yield return buffer[j];

            buffer[j] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

maneira de usar:

```
listaPessoas = listaPessoas.Shuffle().Take(3);
```

Comment: Por que é a melhor maneira?

Comment: Porque é um algoritmo feito para isso, embaralhar uma sequencia finita.

Comment: E o que o torna a melhor maneira de se fazer? Qual o embasamento pra esta afirmação?

Comment: é só você ler no link que coloquei, lá já faz a comparação deste para os outros algoritmos. Pesquise na página por "Comparison with other shuffling algorithms"